# replace space with dash in Zend?

Tags: php, zend-framework

```
    if ($settings->getSetting('que_tags', 0)) {
        $this->addElement('Text', 'qtags', array(
            'label' => Zend_Registry::get('Zend_Translate')->_('Tags'),
            'autocomplete' => 'on',
            'description' => Zend_Registry::get('Zend_Translate')->_('Use commas to separate tags.'),
            'allowEmpty' => false,
            'filters' => array('StringTrim', 'StringToLower', new Engine_Filter_Censor()),
        ));
```

I would like to change this:

"United Kingdom" to "united-kingdom".

I was able to insert `StringToLower` on the code but when I added `SeparatorToDash`, it didn't work.

Is there a simple way to make the change happen by just adding/inserting a line to the code above?

Answer (score 0):

Zend delivers such filter out of the box, the class is called `Zend_Filter_Word_SeparatorToDash`:

```
$form = new Zend_Form_Element('test');
$form->addFilter(new \Zend_Filter_Word_SeparatorToDash());
$form->setValue('United Kingdom united kingdom');
var_dump($form->getValue()); // United-Kingdom-united-kingdom
```

More advanced filtering might require creating filter class from scratch or as an alternative you can always use `Zend_Filter_Callback`:

```
$form = new Zend_Form_Element('test');
$form->addFilter(
    new \Zend_Filter_Callback(
        function ($value) {
            return str_replace(' ', '-', strtolower($value));
        }
    )
);
$form->setValue('United Kingdom united kingdom');
var_dump($form->getValue()); // united-kingdom-united-kingdom
```

For more filters can check zend filter folder, there is quite a lot of them.